# Angular js - Strange behaviour when clearing cache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, local-storage

I am relatively new to Angular.js and am wondering about an error I get each time I clear my cache. Under normal circumstances my app runs without producing any console errors; however, if I clear my cache I always get the following error upon the first page refresh:

```
    TypeError: object is not a function
    at f (http://nakedisland.dev/lib/angular/angular-1.3.0-beta.7/angular.min.js:37:378)
    at h.$eval (http://nakedisland.dev/lib/angular/angular-1.3.0-beta.7/angular.min.js:112:316)
    at h.$digest (http://nakedisland.dev/lib/angular/angular-1.3.0-beta.7/angular.min.js:109:392)
    at h.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (<anonymous>:844:31)
    at h.$apply (http://nakedisland.dev/lib/angular/angular-1.3.0-beta.7/angular.min.js:113:100)
    at h.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30)
    at http://nakedisland.dev/lib/angular/angular-1.3.0-beta.7/angular.min.js:18:243
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://nakedisland.dev/lib/angular/angular-1.3.0-beta.7/angular.min.js:35:202)
    at d (http://nakedisland.dev/lib/angular/angular-1.3.0-beta.7/angular.min.js:18:151)
    at ic (http://nakedisland.dev/lib/angular/angular-1.3.0-beta.7/angular.min.js:18:360)
```

Since these are all internal errors with the angular.min.js file itself it's been difficult to trace anything back to my own code, and since I have several factory services which read from and write to `localStorage` it's necessary that I clear my cache regularly during the testing process.

- What is the meaning of this error? It lists several lines which encounter the error but since the code is minified it's difficult to say which object is not a function.
- Am I missing something? Or doing something incorrectly? (I know it might be hard to answer this without posting a large amount of code from my app, but the app code is very, very large.)
- Since the error is produced only after cache clearing (i.e. not on initial loading from a  new browser) should I even be worried about this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use the minified library, if you want to be able to debug by line. Also, you're using a beta version, so I'm sure there's bugs of some form

Comment: @Ian - Ah yes, after switching back to a stable version of angular the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I often get TypeErrors on page refreshes if my watches are not set up in a strict enough way. Your traceback looks similar to the ones I get.

Any $scope.$watch behavior will fire once on page load when the watch registers, unless you explicitly suppress that. The TypeError can happen when your watch tries to call a function, access an attribute, etc., that briefly does not yet exist (as the page as not fully loaded yet). The error then goes away as all of the objects/functions get defined and straighten themselves out.

If your watch depends on calling functions or accessing attributes that may not be defined yet, you may want to suppress the watch by simply returning if newVal and oldVal are equal, as they are when the watch registers:

```
$scope.$watch("yourVariable", function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if(newValue === oldValue){
    return;
  }
  alert("$watch triggered!");
});
```

Comment: Suspected it might be something like this. Ian's suggestion definitely corrected the specific error I was getting, but another reason I posted here in stack was to learn more about best practices. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, missed that -- and it's interesting that a different version fixed it. Angular version does seem to affect load order/speed. We just upgraded to a new version and exposed all sorts of these holes that hadn't been relevant before.